# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.StackOverflowError cannot be cast to java.lang.Exception

Tags: java, selenium

Actually m facing the below mentioned error while executing my java program

```
  Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.StackOverflowError cannot be cast to java.lang.Exception
```

Actually i have a java class called Test_A where it contains following methods called Login() and Logout()
and have a another java class called Test_B where it contains method VerifyValidUser().

```
class Test_A {

  Test_B b = new Test_B();

  public void login()
  {
     driver.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys(userName);
     driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(password);
     driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();

     b.verifyLoginValidUser();
  }   

  public void logout()
  {
     driver.findElement(By.linkText("SIGN-OFF")).click();
  }
}

class Test_B {

Test_A a = new Test_A()

 public void verifyLoginValidUser()
 {
    if(isElementPresent(By.linkText("SIGN-OFF"))) 
    {
    }
    a.logout();
 }  }
```

So while executing the above code it throws me above metioned error message

Can anyone tel me the reason behind it

Thanks

Actual Stacktrace :

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.StackOverflowError cannot be cast to java.lang.Exception
    at supportlibraries.DriverScript.driveTestExecution(DriverScript.java:106)
    at allocator.ParallelRunner.invokeTestScript(ParallelRunner.java:60)
    at allocator.ParallelRunner.run(ParallelRunner.java:41)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: The point is to post the code which actually throws that exception. No line of code you have posted can by itself cause that exception to be thrown.

Comment: Step 1: post the actual stack trace. Step 2: post the code which includes at least the line of code mentioned at the top of that stack trace, and indicate which line it is (the line number won't tell us much).

Comment: Tip: the code will look like this: `(Exception) t`, and it will most probably appear inside some `catch (Throwable t)` block.

Answer (score 6):

Well the cause of the stack overflow is simple:

```
class Test_A {
  Test_B b = new Test_B();
}

class Test_B {
  Test_A a = new Test_A();
}
```

Constructing an instance of `Test_A` involves constructing an instance of `Test_B`, which involves constructing an instance of `Test_A` etc. You should redesign your classes to remove this cyclic dependency. (There are alternatives which keep the dependency, but add parameterized constructors - while those could work, breaking the dependency would be a much better bet.)

The `ClassCastException` is presumably some broken bit of code casting `Throwable` to `Exception` - unfortunately we can't tell *where* that broken bit of code is without the stack trace. It may not even be your code.

Answer (score 2):

We cannot explain what about your code is causing that exception.

However certain things are obvious:

1. That is not your real code.  The code you have shown us won't compile.  (`Test_A` refers to a `driver` variable that is not defined.
2. That code does not contain a type-cast, so it cannot possibly throw a `ClassCastException`.
3. If some (real) code did attempt to cast a `StackOverflowError` to an `Exception`, it would fail.  `StackOverflowError` is a subtype of `Error` not `Exception`.  If you need to deal with both `Error` and `Exception` objects, use their common supertype - `Throwable`.

---

It looks like Jon Skeet has found the root cause of the original `StackOverflowError`, but it would have been easier for us (and you!) to spot from the exception stacktrace.

Comment: He doesn't need to deal with Error. I'd bet my house on it.

Comment: @EricStein - you are probably right ... though betting your house on it would be unwise :-)

Comment: Yeah, well. That kinda day. :-)

Comment: @ Stephen C : the code which I have posted is not the real one,since i couldnt copy the exact source since m restricted to access internet ..  but my ulitmate aim was to knew the exact reason behind the error which is been throws ...

Comment: @Ganeshja - Not withstanding that, if you want a positive response to your Questions, you should find a way to either provide the real source code, or write/compile/test an equivalent to the real source and post that instead.